# Scikit-learn Column Transformer does not return back feature names

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

I'm trying to use Column Transformer with OneHotEncoder to transform my categorical data :

A quick look at my data :

[image]

I want to do one-hot-encoding for 3 features : 'sex' , 'smoker' , 'region', so I use Column Transformer by scikit-learn. ( I don't want to want to seperate numerical one and categorical one than transform them seperately, I just want to perform them on a single dataset)

My code :

```py
cat_feature = X.select_dtypes(include = 'object') #select only categorical columns 

enc = ColumnTransformer([ ('one_hot_encoder' , OneHotEncoder() , cat_feature ) ] , 
                     remainder = 'passthrough')

X_transformed  =  enc.fit_transform(X)   # transformed version of original data
```

My problem is that, `X_transformed` is then removed all the feature names which is little bit confusing for me to debug :

[image]

So is there anyway to retain my columns' names after doing this transformation? I want to incorporate this transformer into a pipeline so I can't use `pd.get_dummies`.
Thank you!!

Comment: from this link: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.html. return of `ColumnTransformer` is `list` and you need extra library for your question. why do you can't use `pandas`?

Comment: @user1740577 Because I want to make it into a full pipeline, so I can't use pd.get_dummies

Comment: did you see the link that I send?

Comment: yes I saw it, but from what I've read, the only useful one for my case is ```get_feature_names``` but it only returns the categorical columns' name, it does not specify what is the name for column 1 of ```X_transformed``` in my case. That's why I really want to use pd.get_dummies but this one does not allow me to put it into a scikit-learn pipeline.

Comment: Please elaborate on why `get_feature_names` is insufficient. It should provide names for all the columns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

User will have to write custom `Transformer` which does passthrough and supports `get_feature_names`

Steps:

1. Custom `Transformer` which will return pass through columns names via `get_feature_names`
2. Dont use  `remainder = 'passthrough'` but rather use our custom `Transformer`

Use `enc.get_feature_names()` to get the feature list.

**Sample:**

```
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'age': [1,2,3,4],
    'sex': ['male', 'female']*2,
    'bmi': [1.1,2.2,3.3,4.4],
    'children': [1]*4,
    'smoker': ['yes', 'no']*2
})
cat_features = df.select_dtypes(include = 'object').columns
passthrough_features = [c for c in df.columns if c not in cat_features]

class PassthroughTransformer(BaseEstimator):
  def fit(self, X, y = None):
    self.cols = X.columns
    return self

  def transform(self, X, y = None):
    self.cols = X.columns
    return X.values

  def get_feature_names(self):
    return self.cols

enc = ColumnTransformer([ ('1hot' , OneHotEncoder() , cat_features ),
                         ('pass' , PassthroughTransformer(), passthrough_features)])
X_transformed   = enc.fit_transform(df)
pd.DataFrame(X_transformed, columns=enc.get_feature_names())
```

Output:

```
    1hot__x0_female 1hot__x0_male   1hot__x1_no 1hot__x1_yes    pass__age   pass__bmi   pass__children
0   0.0             1.0             0.0         1.0             1.0         1.1         1.0
1   1.0             0.0             1.0         0.0             2.0         2.2         1.0
2   0.0             1.0             0.0         1.0             3.0         3.3         1.0
3    1.0            0.0             1.0         0.0             4.0         4.4         1.0
```

Comment: Ohh I will remember, your answer is so useful to me :D. This will definitely save me !!

Comment: `ColumnTransformer.get_feature_names` already works with a passthrough remainder, so the custom transformer shouldn't be necessary.